# Line chart(FusionCharts) is not showing any data when using with Angular

Tags: angular, fusioncharts

I am trying to render a line chart in UI using angular and fusionCharts but its coming as **No data to display**. Other charts like 'mscolumn2d' are coming properly. Here is my code snippet for .html file and .ts file respectively.

```
    <div class="abc" id="demo-chart">
      <fusioncharts width="100%" height="100%" type="line" dataFormat="json" [dataSource]="demoChartData">
      </fusioncharts>
    </div>
```

```
  createDemoChart(response): void {
    const arrLabel = [];
    const datasetArr = [];
    const arrDataActual = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      arrLabel.push({ label: 'Day ' + i });
      arrDataActual.push({ value: i });
    }
    datasetArr.push({data: arrDataActual });
    this.demoChartData = {
      chart: {
        theme: 'fusion',
        caption: 'Classes over Day',
        xaxisname: 'Day',
        yaxisname: 'No of Classes',
        showvalues: '0',
        anchorRadius: '6',
        anchorBorderThickness: '2',
        anchorBorderColor: '#ccccff',
        anchorBgColor: '#ccccff',
      },
      categories: [{
        category: arrLabel,
      }],
      dataset: datasetArr,
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

"No data to display" chart message is displayed when no "category" is provided in the dataSource, or it is null. In your implementation, check whether "arrLabel" is having the category object array in the prescribed format of FusionCharts.

Also ensure that other objects array like "dataset", "annotations", etc. are receiving the values as per the format in your implementation.

Comment: I have checked it all variables(arrLabel, arrDataActual, datasetArr) are having data and demoChartData variable is also getting populated but graph is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the data structure for `line` and `msline` is not the same. You will need to provide the data or datasets in a different way depending if the chart is a Multi-series chart or a single series chart.

For the single series line chart, try this:

```
createDemoChart(response): void {
  const arrDataActual = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arrDataActual.push({ label: `Day ${i}`, value: i });
  }
  this.demoChartData = {
    chart: {
      theme: 'fusion',
      caption: 'Classes over Day',
      xaxisname: 'Day',
      yaxisname: 'No of Classes',
      showvalues: '0',
      anchorRadius: '6',
      anchorBorderThickness: '2',
      anchorBorderColor: '#ccccff',
      anchorBgColor: '#ccccff',
    },
    data: arrDataActual,
  };
}
```

If you prefer to keep the data structure, then you'll need to change in the html the type from `line` to `msline`:

```
<div class="abc" id="demo-chart">
  <fusioncharts width="100%" height="100%" type="msline" dataFormat="json" [dataSource]="demoChartData">
  </fusioncharts>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the line chart you can take reference here. No data to display chart message is displayed when no "category" is provided in the dataSource, or it is null or mismatch of type

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ng-fusioncharts"]);

app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
  $scope.myDataSource = {
    chart: {
      caption: "Average Fastball Velocity",
      yaxisname: "Velocity (in mph)",
      subcaption: "[2005-2016]",
      numbersuffix: " mph",
      rotatelabels: "1",
      setadaptiveymin: "1",
      theme: "candy"
    },
    data: [
      {
        label: "2005",
        value: "89.45"
      },
      {
        label: "2006",
        value: "89.87"
      },
      {
        label: "2007",
        value: "89.64"
      },
      {
        label: "2008",
        value: "90.13"
      },
      {
        label: "2009",
        value: "90.67"
      },
      {
        label: "2010",
        value: "90.54"
      },
      {
        label: "2011",
        value: "90.75"
      },
      {
        label: "2012",
        value: "90.8"
      },
      {
        label: "2013",
        value: "91.16"
      },
      {
        label: "2014",
        value: "91.37"
      },
      {
        label: "2015",
        value: "91.66"
      },
      {
        label: "2016",
        value: "91.8"
      }
    ]
  };
});
```

To configure the chart - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/angular/angularjs/your-first-chart-using-angularjs

Here is the Demo fiddle - https://codepen.io/pen?&editors=101&layout=left